# Fiji/ImageJ - Measure tool when x and y resolution of image not equal

Tags: resolution, imagej, measure

I have images with unequal resolution in x and y direction. The pixel height is larger than the pixel width. The pixel width and pixel height are saved in Image > Properties.

When I draw an ellipse on the image and try to use the Analyze > Measure tool I get a '0' for both major and minor axis length for the "Fit ellipse" measurement. 
I can only get a proper measurement if I remove the scale of the image, or manually change the pixel height and pixel width to an equal number.

I assume this is a bug, but maybe I'm missing something?

As a workaround I was thinking of writing a small macro that saves pixel height and pixel width, then removes the scale of the image, then measures major and minor axis length in pixel and then  re-applies pixel height and pixel width to the measurements.

But I can't find the command for reading out the resolution. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `Set Measurements...` command](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:Set-Measurements...) states in the description of the **Fit ellipse** parameter:

> Note that ImageJ cannot calculate the major and minor axis lengths if
>   *Pixel Aspect Ratio* in the `Analyze▷Set Scale…` dialog is not *1.0*.

Your workaround should work, just use the [`getPixelSize(unit, pixelWidth, pixelHeight)` macro function](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#getPixelSize).